# An ImageVIew inside a setOnClickListener gives me a NullPointerException when setting Visibility

Tags: android, imageview

I want to set an ImageView as invisible when I click a button inside a fragment.

It gives me this error java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    bcl.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            heart1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.heart_1);
        heart1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
     });
```

I don't know what it could be. I have tried the things that other stackoverflow pages said, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: where are you settings this code .. inside an adapter ?

Answer (score 2):

Use Fragment context for initialize ImageView instead of `v` :

```
bcl.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        heart1 = (ImageView) Your_Frg_Name.this.findViewById(R.id.heart_1);
        heart1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Ah, didn't read fully. I missed that it was inside of a `Fragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
heart1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.heart_1);
```

to

```
heart1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.heart_1);
```

Remove the "v" before `findViewById()`. When you do this, it is looking in `v` for the `ImageView` and since `v` represents the `Button` clicked it obviously won't find the `ImageView` inside of the `Button`.

This is assuming that this code is in the `Activity`. If it is, say inside of a `Dialog`, and you have inflated a different `layout` which contains this `ImageView` then you would use the inflated `layout` in front of `findViewById()`.

Answer (score 0):

heart1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.heart_1);

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create the object in oncreate

heart1 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.heart_1);

and then in your setclicklistlistner

```
bcl.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    heart1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
});
```

Try avoid creating object every time